# Losing item from session intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

i am little lost...

we are using sqlserver session sharing and on our production (2 servers) and staging (2 servers), i am loosing one item only from the sessions intermittently. Both, staging and production are load balanced and on same servers but point to different databases.

My local development and the dev site (different server) do not have this issue. These both use the dev database.

Sql server session tables and sprocs are specific to the environment since these are setup in dev, staging or production database.

Code to place items in the session

```
SessionService.AddItem(SessionKeys.LoggedInUser, user);  //this is always available

SessionService.AddItem(SessionKeys.Impersonator, inhouseUser); //this is lost intermittently


public static void AddItem(string key, object value)
        {
            CheckSessionAvailability();
            HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
        }
```

Getting the item from the session:

```
User inhouseUser = SessionService.GetItem<User>(SessionKeys.Impersonator);


public static T GetItem<T>(string key)
        {
            object item = null;
            CheckSessionAvailability();
            item = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
            if ((item != null) && !(item is T))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot convert");
            }

            return (T)item;
        }
```

Comment: do you have a machine key defined in the web.config?

Comment: Yes <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

Comment: I have recycled the app pools and restarted the staging site. This didn't help.

Comment: I have tested staging nodes (2 instances) via ip and both of the session items are available.

Comment: I have changed the key and instead of putting the full user object, now i am only putting userid for the second item. It is stll doing the same thing.

Comment: I have changed the code and now instead of working with two session items, i have created a new property in "User" entity. I am assigning the user id of the impersonator to this property. Local dev and the dev site work normal, where as on staging and production, this is coming back as null. 

'//adding the inhouse user's user id to the client
            client.ImpersonatedByUserId = inhouseUser.UserId;

            SessionService.AddItem(SessionKeys.LoggedInUser, client);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our staging site is load balanced... we disabled node 2 and only made node 1 active. It worked without any issue.

Initially, we had no persistence enabled on the staging or production sites.  We enabled cookie-based persistence on the staging site, and while we verified the persistence cookies were coming through in the browser, my page still wasn't consistently working as expected.  We switched the load balancer to use persistence based on client IP instead, and then it did appear to be working on staging. Will implement the same on production.